# LiveData observer trigger only once with empty value

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-livedata

Everything working API request return response but, activity observer is triggered only first time with empty value and when response comes from request observer didn't see the changes.

Activity:

```
viewModel.jobQuestions.observe(this, Observer { list ->
            list?.let {
                jobQuestionsRv.apply {
                  setAdapterData(list)
                }
            }
        })
```

ViewModel:

```
class JobQuestionsViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: Repository) : ViewModel() {

private val _jobQuestions = MutableLiveData<List<QuestionModel>>()
val jobQuestions: LiveData<List<QuestionModel>> = _jobQuestions

init {
    _jobQuestions.postValue(repository.getQuestions())
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
override fun getQuestions(): List<QuestionModel> {

    var questionsList = ArrayList<QuestionModel>()

    apiRequests?.questions()?.enqueue(object : retrofit2.Callback<List<QuestionModel>> {
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<List<QuestionModel>>?,
            response: Response<List<QuestionModel>>
        ) {
            response.body()?.let {
                questionsList.addAll(response.body())

            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<QuestionModel>>?, t: Throwable?) {
            questionsList.clear()

        }
    })

    return questionsList
}
```

Comment: `enqueue` is asynchronous function, it means that you return empty `questionsList` before calling `onResponse` where it is filled. You can use and return `LivaData` in `getQuestions`, and in `onResponse` use `setValue`/`postValue` method of this `livedata`

Comment: Yes, i tried this and it`s work, but i think that is better solution to generate livedata in viewModel, can i achive this somehow?

Comment: Then you have to pass callbacks in `getQuestions` that will be called in `onResponse` and `onFailure`

Comment: How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is the type of your network request function?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return LiveData from your repository, you can do following:

In repository, change type of questionsList to MutableLiveData and post the value whenever it's returned from callback:

```
override fun getQuestions(): LiveData<QuestionModel> {

    val questionsList = MutableLiveData<List<QuestionModel>>()

    apiRequests?.questions()?.enqueue(object : retrofit2.Callback<List<QuestionModel>> {
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<List<QuestionModel>>?,
            response: Response<List<QuestionModel>>
        ) {
            response.body()?.let {
                questionsList.postValue(response.body())

            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<QuestionModel>>?, t: Throwable?) {
            questionsList.postValue(emptyList())

        }
    })

    return questionsList
}
```

In ViewModel, just call getQuestions():

```
class JobQuestionsViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: Repository) : ViewModel() {

    val jobQuestions: LiveData<List<QuestionModel>> = repository.getQuestions()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If data that you are getting in observer throwing any exception then that observer will not called again until you set that observer again or preventing the exception.

Comment: I checked before asked here and the response comes without any exceptions